# Method Not Implemented PhpMyAdmin

Tags: methods, phpmyadmin

Getting this error when clicking the edit button for a record in phpmyadmin

```
Method Not Implemented

GET to /_pma/tbl_change.php not supported.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Could this be a problem with "mod_security" and if so, what is "mod_security" and how could we fix it?

If not, what could be causing this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the newest version of phpMyAdmin on your server. If you are running it via XAMPP, also download the newest version of it. I had the same problem and that solved it for me.